# How many elements have order $12$ in a cyclic group of order $12$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there a general formula to determine how many elements have a certain order in a cyclic group? (I don't know abstract algebra but this particular knowledge is required for one of my classes)

Comment: In a cyclic group of order $n$, there are $\phi(n)$ generators.

Comment: There is a formula. You could have a go at working it out. One way to think about this is to note that you exclude the elements of orders $1,2,3,4,6$ - how many of those are there? The group you are working with is equivalent to the integers modulo $12$ under addition, so it should be possible to write down the order of each of the twelve elements of that, and explore the pattern.

Comment: This is called euler's phi function to add to David Wheeler's comment.

Comment: You need to read about Euler's $\phi$ function, as already suggested in comments. Its basic properties are that $\phi(p^{t}) = p^{t-1}(p-1)$ when $p$ is a prime number and $t$ is a positive integer, and that $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$ when $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime integers greater than $1$.

Comment: So $\phi(12) = 4$ so that gives me $4$ elements of order $12$, but how can I tell how many elements of order $4$ there are in the cyclic group of $12$ elements? Can I apply $\phi$ regardless of the group I am working in, or is it just a coincidence that $\phi$ in this case gives me all the exact number of elements that have order $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, and $6$ (applying $\phi$ to these gives me $1, 1, 2, 2, 2$ respectively, which all turn out to be the correct answers)?

Comment: No, it's not a coincidence-it is well-known that: $n = \sum_{d|n} \phi(d)$

Comment: Yes indeed, $\phi(12) = 4,$ and as remarked in earlier comments, a cyclic group of order $n >1$ always has $\phi(n)$ elements of order $n$ ( ie $\phi(n)$ generators).